# Bulk crop pictures

Tags: command-line

I have many pictures in a folder (their size may vary) and I would like to split them in two as follows. For each image.jpg I would like two files:

- imageA.jpg which comes from image.jpg by cropping out the left 50%
- imageB.jpg which comes from image.jpg by cropping out the right 50%

Is there an easy way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple command to do what you want:

```
for f in *.{jpg,jpeg}; do convert "${f}" -crop 2x1@ "${f}"; done;
```

**Note:** If a file is called `image.jpg` the left half will be image-0.jpg and the right half will be image-1.jpg.

For this command to work, you have to first change to the directory where all the image files are. For example, if the image files are in the folder `~/path/to/images` then you will need to first use the command:

```
cd ~/path/to/images
```

followed by:

```
for f in *.{jpg,jpeg}; do convert "${f}" -crop 50%x100% "${f}"; done;
```

**Note slightly the different crop option.**

You may want to put the two commands in a bash script.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! This helped! I used it followed by mmv in order to get the names I wanted.